# Why can't I set an array to API data using useState()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

So I have an app which uses Movies API. I make an API request, then I pass this data to an array using useState hook, basically my code looks like the following:

```
const App = () => {

type MovieType = {    //declaring type
    rate: string,
    title: string,
    tagline: string,
    date: string,
};

 interface MovieProps {   //extending an interface with MovieType
 movies: MovieType[],
  }
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<MovieType[]>([]);   //useState for setting an array to data from api

  useEffect(() =>{
      fetchMovies();
  }, [])

  async function fetchMovies() {   //function for fetching movies
      try{
        let apikey = '{api_key}';
        let url: string = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=';
        url = url + apikey;
        const response = await axios.get<[MovieType]>(url);
        setMovies(response.data);
      }catch(e){
        alert('Error');
      }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <Hero movies={movies}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So basically, when I run the app, I get an alert with an error. I've tried renaming the useState, so it differs from props in the `<Hero>` component, and then I could pass data to an array. But when I do it with `[movies, setMovies]` it doesn't work. So I guess the problem is somewhere in passing props or `type MovieType`, but I can't figure out what exactly could be the problem.

Edit: an error I get in try catch:

```
TypeError: movies.map is not a function
```

I have `movies.map` in Container component, which gets movies from the Hero, which gets it from the App:

```
const Container = ({movies}: MovieProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {movies.map((movie) =>(
          <MovieItem movie={movie} key={movie.title}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I don't know why `movies.map` is not a function if movies is basically an array.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: The error and the structure of the response data would both be helpful to see

Comment: i get no particular error in the console, but i get an error from the try..catch. i tried to remove `setMovies(respones.data)` line and there wasn't any error, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Darcy i added an error message and also added more details

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "await fetchMovies" instead of just "fetchMovies" but since you can't make useEffect async try something like this...

```
 useEffect(() =>{
      async function foo(){
        await fetchMovies();
     }
      foo();
  }, []);
```

Hopefully it works!

Comment: actually the problem isn't really in useEffect, cause fetchMovies works, i get an error from the `try..catch`, but i can't set an array to data. I renamed useState and it worked, so i think it has something to do with props in `<Hero movies={movies}>`

Comment: @Jesse `useEffect` doesn't need to be async as it isn't returning anything from `fetchMovies` (which is already asynchronous)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Container` component attempting to iterate over `movies` before `fetchMovies` has finished getting the data. Essentially, you're trying to iterate over an empty array. To reveal this, and for future debugging purposes, include a `console.log(movies)` in `Container`.

To fix, simply include `movies.length` as a check before you map over the data:

```js
const Container = ({movies}: MovieProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {movies.length && movies.map((movie) =>(
          <MovieItem movie={movie} key={movie.title}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```